# Only allow an Openshift app to be connected with another one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, jetty, openshift

I am currently using the free version of Openshift. I have a scalable ruby on rails + postgres app using 2 of my gears and have a separate (potentially scalable) elasticsearch app using the 3rd gear.

The elasticsearch app was generated using https://github.com/rbrower3/openshift-elasticsearch-cartridge

Since the elasticsearch runs as an app on its own url then that leaves it open to attack from the outside world if someone found out the web address of it.

I have considered the [elasticsearch-jetty](https://github.com/pmusa/elasticsearch-jetty/) plugin, although I've not managed to lock it down with a username and password successfully yet, but was wondering if there were any other options for limiting access to my elasticsearch Openshift app somehow, eg using apache somehow, so that only my other app can make connections to it (which would need to be read and write - updating the elasticsearch index as well as selecting data from it).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most basic answer is we support .htaccess for Apache where you can specify a username and password. The other option is to add some other Auth option in front of your elasticsearch by modifying the code in the repo to do that. I am not familiar enough with a default elasticsearch install to know what specific mechanism you can use.